# Is it possible to do fancy formatting for page footers with weasyprint?

Tags: python, pdf, formatting, weasyprint

weasyprint understands certain custom css directives, such as:

```
 @bottom-right {
   content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages) "
 }
```

which places a "Page 1 of 4" style counter at the bottom right of each pdf page weasyprint generates.

I'd like to produce slightly fancier formatting for my footers - for example, I'd like to be able to show some portions in bold, and others as italic, like so:

Page **1** *of* **4**

Is this feasible with weasyprint? If so, how do I instruct weasyprint to use this kind of formatting - I'll take CSS based solutions, though I'd much rather do this programmatically using the weasyprint library from python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Page **1** *of* **4**" is not doable at the moment. If you’re interested, please send comments to [www-style@w3.org](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) about what a new CSS feature could look like to do this kind of thing.

What works is:

- Page-margin rules like `@bottom-right`, with the `content` property. You get up to 16 such boxes per page, but parts of one box can not be styled differently.
- Elements with `position: fixed` are repeated on every page. With tricks like `top: 100%; right: 0` you can position them like headers or footers, but they are identical on every page. `counter(page)` doesn’t work there.

By the way, I do not usually watch StackOverflow for WeasyPrint question. Writing to WeasyPrint’s mailing list or issue tracker will get more response.

Comment: How do you add an image to the content property?

Comment: @josh `content: url(foo.png)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Simon. Thanks. I tried this with a local file (full path, and a mix of relative paths) and couldn't get this to work. It did work using a url from the web.

Comment: @josh you may need to specify a base URL for the document. But it's hard to say in this small comment box, consider filing an issue with a reduced reproducible test case on the WeasyPrint Github issue tracker.

Comment: @josh or in a new stack overflow question

Comment: @SimonSapin can you answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710321/css-rules-not-working-specially-inside-page-for-update-header-and-footer?noredirect=1#comment119156536_57710321